# Customized radio buttons - hidden default buttons showing up on Safari on iPad

Tags: jquery, ios, css, ipad, safari

I have -moz-appearance: none, -webkit-appearance: none set on these buttons, but for some reason I still keep getting an error by which the default radio button selectors show up where they should be hidden. This is happening on an iPad Air (about a year or two old) on Safari.

The JSFiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/p8sdu1ut/7/

I took a screen shot of what it looks like and you can view this at this link:

[image: http://theloneprospector.com/issue.gif]

```css
.radio-selector {
  position: absolute;
}

.radio-selector input {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.largeRadio {
  background-image: url(http://theloneprospector.com/largeUnchecked.png);
}

.radio-selector input:active+.radio-label {
  opacity: .9;
}

.radio-selector input:checked+.radio-label {
  -webkit-filter: none;
  -moz-filter: none;
  filter: none;
  background-image: url(http://theloneprospector.com/largeChecked.png);
}

.radio-label {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in;
}

.radio-label:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
  -moz-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
  filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-selector">
  <div class="Q1YES">
    <input type="radio" id="Q1YES" name="currentUser" value="1">
    <label class="radio-label largeRadio" for="Q1YES" onclick=""></label>
  </div>
  <div class="Q1NO">
    <input type="radio" id="Q1NO" name="currentUser" value="0">
    <label class="radio-label largeRadio" for="Q1NO" onclick=""></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't have an ipad to check for myself, but can you set their position off screen instead?  `position:absolute; left: -999;`

Answer (score 1):

To hide input (radio, checkbox) on Safari you can use next styles:

```
input[type="radio"],
input[type="checkbox"] {
  appearance: none;
  display: none
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same problem with Safari on iOS. 
Here is a simple solution:

```
input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}
```

This worked like a charm.

Comment: Worked for me.. Thanks!